# How to get PDB info and backplane info from IPMI or from OS linux?

Tags: ipmi

Can i get power distribution block (PDB) part number/serial number and backplane part number/serial number from IPMI or from OS linux ?

I have server with motherboard "supermicro X9DRT-HF+"

Thanking you in advance